# Website in IIS only reachable via ::1

Tags: windows-server-2016, iis-10

I am using Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10.0 and I have configured a website in IIS Server Manager which binds to port 9999 and should listen to all IP addresses.

`netstat -an | findstr 9999` shows the following which looks fine to me (ABHÖREN means LISTENING):

`TCP    0.0.0.0:9999           0.0.0.0:0              ABHÖREN`

I can establish a connection via browser or telnet using `localhost` as hostname (which resolves to `::1`) or using `::1` directly. But trying this with the servers LAN IP address (e.g. `192.168.178.65`) or the IPv4 loopback address (`127.0.0.1`) does not work, I get a timeout.

I have tried the following:

- disable Windows Firewall
- disable Windows Defender
- using `netsh http add iplisten 0.0.0.0` and `netsh http add iplisten 192.168.178.65`

Also I think there is something that blocks the connection. Immeadetly after rebooting the server I can establish a connection via an IPv4 Address but it stops working after a moment.

Are there any things I can check or try?

Comment: It certainly sounds like a misconfigured firewall. Have you got a third party firewall product installed?

Comment: I do not use any third party firewall software and I have disabled the Windows Firewall (via control panel and I stopped the firewall service).

Answer (score 0):

After disabling DirectAccess via group policies I got it working. I do not really understand the relation between DirectAccess and my problem but I am glad it works now.

Comment: DirectAccess itself injects into IIS (if I remember correctly), so without knowing its detailed configuration (I don't either) it is recommended to run it on a separate machine, so it won't interfere your web sites (like you did). This applies to many Microsoft products (SharePoint/Exchange and more).